# How to copy IntBuffer into int[]

Tags: java, nio

While working with off heap buffers one might want to copy them into array.
Let's assume we don't know if buffer is off or on heap. 
How to fill the implementation?

```
IntBuffer b = ... // could be off or on -heap
int[] array = toArray(b)

public int[] toArray(IntBuffer b) {
    //???
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#array--

Comment: `int[] array = b.array()`

Comment: This won't work for the off heap buffers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should work for direct buffers and array backed buffers.

It should also take into account shared buffers so for example a buffer `[0, 1, 2, 3]` sliced in half would allow you to call `toArray()` on both buffer slices and return what you expect.

It will copy the full contents of that particular buffer (whether sliced or not) with no regards to the positions or limits. It has plenty of side effects for non-array backed buffers though, so don't write code like this (or document the side effects at least).

```
public int[] toArray(IntBuffer b) {
    if(b.hasArray()) {
        if(b.arrayOffset() == 0)
            return b.array();

        return Arrays.copyOfRange(b.array(), b.arrayOffset(), b.array().length);
    }

    b.rewind();
    int[] foo = new int[b.remaining()];
    b.get(foo);

    return foo;
}
```

since `array()` returns the actual backing array, any changes are reflected in the buffer. If you don't want that, `clone()` the array before returning it (not needed for sliced buffers, since `copyOfRange` is used for them).

---

There are probably some unconsidered edge cases there, so if you find any, put a comment below and I'll reward you with a (nasty) surprise.

Comment: I sometimes saw the check together with `(b.arrayOffset() == 0)`. Maybe you know if it's necessary?
What about calling `b.rewind()` before `get()`? I think this could be helpful to   emphasise that.